# Timer not working properly on iis server in global file

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, global-asax

I am currently facing two problems with asp.net web application

1. I have timer which calls a function every 3600 ms(1 min) but if the system is ideal say for few minutes, then the timer stops, t o start the timer again i have to access the website through url or restart the server. Why so?
2. System timer steadily increases the interval through seconds due to which I am not able to compare time with Datetime.now method

Here is the simple code which i have written in global.asax file:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Timers.Timer Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    Timer.Interval = 1000 * 60;
    Timer.AutoReset = true;
    //Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Run);
    Timer.Enabled = true;
}

void Run(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var time = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    var min = DateTime.Now.Minute;
    InspectionMailer insp = new InspectionMailer();
    // this condition gets failed after few minutes due to increase in time interval 
    if ((time == 15 && min == 0) || (time == 15 && min == 26) || time == 15 && min == 40)
    {
        insp.Send("EQT");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go into your IIS settings and change the Application Pool 'Idle Time-out' to something else. I think it defaults to 15 minutes.

`IIS > Application Pools > (Right-click) Advanced Settings > Idle time-out (minutes)`

To elaborate, your application pool is falling asleep. You have to either increase the idle time-out to prevent it sleeping, or create something additional that hits a URL on a timer to keep it awake.